# How to add an image to the LaunchScreen in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I want to add an image to the *LaunchScreen*, which appears at first of the app and disappear after a few seconds. It only contains the name of the application and the version. Under the name of the app I want to have the logo of my firm.

I created a `ViewController` named `LaunchScreenViewController` and create a variable in my *headerfile* called `imageView`. If I add the created class `LaunchScreenViewController` to the `ViewController`, I get an error

```
Launch screens may not set custom classnames
```

I don't know how to add a logo to the launch screen.

**My tries:**

## LaunchScreenViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LaunchViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView
@end
```

## LaunchScreenViewController.m

```
#import "LaunchScreenViewController.h"

@interface LaunchScreenViewController
@end

@implementation LaunchScreenViewController
@end
```

Comment: are you using storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, if you create a new projects, you have two storyboards, the main and the LaunchScreen.

Comment: did u try keeping an imageview on launch screen storyboard

Comment: Yes, I add an UIImageView to the storyboard LaunchScreen, but how to display a logo?

Comment: you can give the image to imageview in the storyboard itself.

Comment: Wow, the solution was fast and good. Thanks, it's exactly the way, I was looking for =)

Comment: From [Arthur Gevorkyan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2799410/arthur-gevorkyan): [Tutorial on Using a Launch Screen Storyboard](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your project setting it must be like following image to show `xib` file as `Launch Screen`.

[image]

Also check `Plist File` for below image `property`.

[image]

If you want `Splash Screen` say for some more time then update `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    sleep(3);
    return YES;
}
```